# In general, does showing the existence of a set specified using set-builder notation consist of showing it is non-empty?

Tags: logic, set-theory

The axiom schema of comprehension/separation is: $\forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff x \in A \land \phi)$. This implies that ANY set specified by the set-builder notation is either the empty set or a subset of another, already existing set.

**I wanted to ask,** is then the general meaning of "show that set $\{x:P(x)\}$ exists", show that it is non-empty?

I ask, because given the above axiom schema, it clearly exists, the meaningful question being whether it is non-empty. Furthermore, I ask because I don't know whether there are alternative formulations of axiomatic set theory of ZFC, maybe using a different axiom schema of comprehension, where "the set $\{x:P(x)\}$ exists" could mean something else. Maybe set-builder notation makes it possible to formulate something that looks like a set but ends up not being one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the axiom (schema) only guarantees that *at least* one set $B$ as described exists (per given $A$ and $\phi$). It is another axiom, Extensionality, that guarantees that $B$ is unique. And it is the latter fact that motivates a special notation as shorthand for „the unique set $B$ as per Separation for given $A$ and $\phi$“. Naturally, that notation *must* incorporate both $A$ and $\phi$. The *class* builder notation $\{\,x : \phi(x)\,\}$ clearly lacks the reference to $A$. Instead, $\{\,x\in A:\phi(x)\,\}$ is commonly used. For the latter, it is immediate that the set exists (namely, this is precisely what the corresponding instance of Separation guarantees); for the former, a class us defined instead and it requires proof that this class is in fact a set under certain circumstances.

Comment: "it requires proof that this class is in fact a set under certain circumstances" entirely clarified the issue for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> ... given the above axiom schema, it clearly exists...

No, the axiom schema does *not* imply that the set $\{x : P(x)\}$ exists (I presume that $P(x)$ is what you have also written as $\phi$).

For example, taking $P(x)$ to be the formula $x \not\in x$, it is known that the set $\{x : x \not\in x\}$ does not exist. That's the outcome of Russell's paradox.

What you are missing is that your set builder notation $\{x : P(x)\}$ does not specify the set $A$ that is needed to apply the axiom schema. What that axiom schema tells you is that for any set $A$, and for any formula $P(x)$, the set that is expressed in set builder notation as $\{x \in A : P(x)\}$ *exists*.

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The empty set definitely exists, so if $P(x)$ is always false, then the set $\{x \mid P(x)\}$ exists.

However, there is eg no such thing as the set $\{x \mid \mathrm{true}\}$ - this would be an universal set, which leads to a contradiction.

Where separation is relevant is that if we know that there exists a set $A$ such that $P(x)$ implies $x \in A$, then the set $\{x \mid P(x)\}$ exists.

Comment: the universal set example was helpful, thank you!